# LDAP parameters settings

Tags: ldap, openldap

i`m trying to setup LDAP user authentication with openldap for the page accesible at:

```
http://serverip/uploadify-php/index.php
```

Im having difficulties undestanding what i should set under **dc**=my-domain and **dc**=com parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the parameter to which you refer is the `base object` or `base DN` of a naming context supported by the server. The value to be used here (which can be any distinguished name, not necessarily of the form `dc=company,dc=com`). The value for the parameter is determined by the naming context, which can be obtained from:

- the server administrators or
- the root DSE

For more information about the root DSE, see [LDAP: The Root DSE](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/the-root-dse.html).

Comment: Im running this on a virtual machine, so i`m the admin of this computer. Im only trying to test this solution before moving it to a real server which has a domain in that form. Im sorry if im stupid, but i don`t know how to set those two parameters without having a domain.

Comment: @RunoTheDog It has nothing to do with 'having a domain'. It has to do with how you have defined the root object in your LDAP database. Only you know the answer to that.

Comment: Well, i`m following this tutorial: http://www.google.si/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCUQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.krugerville.com%2Fcentos6%2Fconfiguring-openldap-server-on-centos-6.html&ei=mxiVT8eYFYnhtQaCnejYBA&usg=AFQjCNHQVkZwrcCRGRRs-eyu4dj2Tx_flw&sig2=UXPIIruhuCXoi8tDGGHXqw

Comment: That example uses the naming context `dc=example,dc=com`

Comment: @RunoTheDog and it also says "Edit the line: `olcSuffix: dc=my-domain,dc=com` to `olcSuffix: dc=example,dc=com` or whatever". The new value of 'whatever' is completely up to you. You have to decide it when designing your LDAP database and your LDAP clients have to user it when looking it up.

Comment: Ok, it took a while, but I finally figured, I could put all of the content of my webpage folder in the /html folder. That way I am able to access my page directly. Now, I`m having trouble setting up the authentication; I already created a test user with the uid:bloh and password:123 using apache directory studio. I`ve set up the centos clients with authconfig-tui by following this tutorial: http://huinn.wordpress.com/2012/01/01/centos-6-2-ldap-with-tls-quick-dirty/ and on windows machines I used pGina, but it is not working (the plugin LDAPAuth is already built in this version of pGina).

Comment: @RunoTheDog New questions should not be asked in comments. Most people won't see them, and those that do are likely to ignore them. There is no answer-a-comment-in-a-comment facility, no votes, etc.